# Why do 11pt fonts of gnome-terminal look so much bigger when running under KDE compared to GNOME/Unity?

Tags: gnome, font-size, kde-plasma

I am trying to explore KDE a bit, but many of the tools I rely on have fonts that appear so much bigger under KDE than Gnome even though the chosen font size is the same and the resolution is the same (1920x1200).  I have noticed this for **gnome-terminal** as well as **GNU Emacs 23.1** (compiled with xft).

I run Ubuntu 11.10 if that helps.

Is there a simple explanation?

Thanks!

SetJmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a font DPI configuration issue:

http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/install-boot-login/461359-switched-gnome-kde-now-my-system-font-size-etc-all-screwy.html

The Font Settings menu has the appropriate dialogue.  In my case changing to 96 DPI fixed the problem.